# Async class delegate (async / await)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, async-await

I would like to get a async delegate. I have created a simple code to understand where are my problem. I have been reading async/await documentation but all cases was simples.

My Code to apply async delegate:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        int code;
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog (this);
        dialog.Select ();

        dialog.Finish += (t) =>
        {
            code = t.code;
        };

            //  
            //Wait until app executes dialog.finish(). 
            //I don't want put the UIAlertView in "dialog.Finish".
            //

        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView ("dialog later", "item select " + code, null, null, "ok");
        alert.Show ();
        }

    public class CustomType
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomDialog
    {
        public event DialogoEventHandle Finish;
        public delegate void DialogoEventHandle (CustomType t);
        private UIViewController view;

        public CustomDialog(UIViewController view)
        {
            this.view = view;
        }

        protected void OnFinish(CustomType t)
        {
            if (Finish != null)
                Finish(t);
        }


        public void Select()
        {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((object sender) =>
                {
                    //operation
                    Thread.Sleep (400);

                    this.view.InvokeOnMainThread (() =>
                    {
                        OnFinish (new CustomType () { code = 5 });
                    });
                });
        }
            }
       }
```

Comment: Method `CalculateAsync` is named async but really not

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks but I have problem with OnFinish delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your overall approach. You shouldn't use an event based API, you should use a continuation based API. So your dialog becomes much simpler:

```
public class CustomDialog
{
    public async Task<CustomType> SelectAsync()
    {
        //perform some work on the UI thread

        var customTypeInstance = await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                //operation
                Thread.Sleep(400);

                return new CustomType {code = 5};
            });

        //perform some more work on the UI thread, using the received instance
        return customTypeInstance;
    }
}
```

Here, you introduce an asynchronous *SelectAsync* method, on which you could later *await*. This way you don't have to perform the complex orchestration required while using events.

Now the consumption of the dialog will look easier as well:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    ShowAlertOnSelectCompletion(new CustomDialog());
}

private async void ShowAlertOnSelectCompletion(CustomDialog dialog)
{
    var customType = await dialog.SelectAsync();

    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView ("dialog later", "item select " + customType.code, null, null, "ok");
    alert.Show ();
}
```

To sum it up:

- Put the required UI preparation logic inside the *SelectAsync* method, before the *await*.
- Offload heavy calculations/logic to the background thread using *Task.Run* and get the task result using the *await* keyword.
- Put the required post-calculation logic after *awaiting*.
- In order to use the calculations' result, *await* on the task returned from the *SelectAsync* method inside a method which by itself is defined as *async* (returning *void* from such a method is a bad practice, but you don't want to wait for the task's completion, it seems, so it is pretty safe in this case).

Comment: You don't need `async` and `await` in `Select()`, just return the `Task` directly. Also, the method should be called `SelectAsync()`.